Why is Wolverine not sending message
I use WolverineFx as a framework of choice for building my app.
Now I have two micro-services. Order-service, Event-service.
My endpoint is like this:
[WolverinePost("/order")]
[Transactional]
public static async Task<Ok> ExecuteAsync(CreateOrderRequest request, IMessageContext messaging, ClaimsPrincipal principal, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    foreach (var order in request.OrdersToCreate)
    {
        var orderCreated = order.OrderType switch
        {
            { Code : "BasicOrder" } => await messaging.InvokeAsync<OrderDto>(CreateBasicOrderCommands.FromRequest(request), cancellationToken),
            { Code : "LimitedOrder" } => await messaging.InvokeAsync<OrderDto>(CreateLimitedOrderCommands.FromRequest(request), cancellationToken),
            { Code : "AdvancedOrder" } => await messaging.InvokeAsync<OrderDto>(CreateAdvancedOrderCommands.FromRequest(request), cancellationToken),
            _ => throw new NotSupportedException("The specified OrderType { order.OrderType.Code } is not supported.")
        } 

        await messaging.PublishAsync(new AddNewEventMessage()
            {
                Timestamp = DateTimeOffset.Now,
                Type = EventType.OrderingEvent,
                Message = $"New order created - Id : {orderCreated.Id}.",
                User = principal?.Identity?.Name ?? "Service"
            });      
    }

    return TypedResults.Ok();
}

The CreateXXXOrderCommand handler looks like this:
[Transactional]
public static async Task<OrderDto> Handle(CreateBasicOrderCommands command, ApplicationDbContext dbContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var order = BasicOrder.FromCommand(command);
    await dbContext.Orders.AddAsync(order, cancellationToken);
    return order.ToDto(); 
}

My Wolverine configuration look like this (apart the queue name, the configuration is the same for both services)
.UseWolverine((context, opts) =>
{
    opts.Discovery.IncludeAssembly(typeof(Program).Assembly);
    opts.Services.Scan(s =>
    {
        s.TheCallingAssembly();
        s.WithDefaultConventions();
        s.LookForRegistries();
    });

    // Enrolling all queues into the
    // durable inbox/outbox processing
    opts.Policies.UseDurableOutboxOnAllSendingEndpoints();
    opts.Policies.UseDurableInboxOnAllListeners();
    opts.Policies.UseDurableLocalQueues();

    // Setting up Sql Server-backed message storage
    var connectionString = context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
    opts.PersistMessagesWithSqlServer(connectionString!);
    opts.UseEntityFrameworkCoreTransactions();
    opts.Policies.AutoApplyTransactions();

    opts.ListenToRabbitQueue("OrderService");
    opts.UseRabbitMq(cfg =>
        {
            var conStr = context.Configuration.GetSection("Api").GetValue<string>("RabbitMq");
            cfg.Uri = new Uri(cfg2.RabbitMq);              
        })
        .UseConventionalRouting()
        .AutoProvision()
        .AutoPurgeOnStartup();

    opts.UseFluentValidation();
})
.ApplyOaktonExtensions();

Now, the problem I have is that when I execute the above endpoint, it will insert new order in the database, but it will NOT send the event. (I know because I am not receiving it in the EventService), also in the table

wolverine_incomming_envelope

there is only one record and it's status is 'Handled' but message type is not of the event type.
But if I change the code and move the logic that sends the event to the Command handler and use cascading messages then it will be sent. But at that point the Id of the newly inserted order is not know because the transaction is not finished jet.
So my questions are:

Why is it not sending the event in the above scenario?
How can I make inserting all the orders transactional, so that if inserting one order fails, it should rollback all the orders?

Thanks
